# adding data to php array within a loop

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am parsing data from a website via xml that always changes so I do not know what data to search for, just the location. I get the data by calling upon the specific class for the data needed. Within this class that is retrieved, there are only certain things I need retrieved. So for example, I retrieve the class .candy. Now .candy corresponds to different parts on the website so let us say that candy retrieves "Cookies Chocolate gummy bear". I only want "chocolate".

My idea was to put everything into an array an array and then access it. Assume the array is called test, then I would want to access  "chocolate" by $test[1];

It is not working for me (says array is out of bounds whenever I put a number bigger than 0) and I was wondering if anyone knows where my mistake is within my code? Please note that the above was purely an example for better understanding and not the actually data I need.

Thank you

```
function getData($html)                             
{                               
    @$doc=new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xml=simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
    //$images=$xml->xpath('//[]');
    $info=$xml->xpath('//*[@class="date"]'); 
    $arr= array();

    foreach ($info as $img) {                                 
        $arr= array($img);          
    }
    return $arr[3];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `$arr` in every loop. `$arr[] = $img;` should work.

Example:

```
function getData($html)
{       
    @$doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
    $info = $xml->xpath('//*[@class="date"]'); 
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($info as $img)
    {
        $arr[] = $img;
    }

    return $arr[3];
}
```

Comment: Ah yes what a silly mistake. Thank you very much, will accept!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($info as $img) {
    $arr[] = $img;
}
```